# H2 tag auto ID in php string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to write a wordpress filter that autoparses the content and takes the following:

```
<h2>lesson 1 bannanas</h2>
```

and replaces it with

```
<h2 id="lesson-1-bannanas">lesson 1 bannanas</h2>
```

So that I can then link people directly to sections of a page or blogpost. How would I do this without resorting to something as heavy as DOMDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a coherent input like that, then you can use regular expressions. In this case it's both very acceptable and simple:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback("#<(h[1-6])>(.*?)</\\1>#", "retitle", $html);

function retitle($match) {
    list($_unused, $h2, $title) = $match;

    $id = strtolower(strtr($title, " .", "--"));

    return "<$h2 id='$id'>$title</$h2>";
}
```

The id conversion needs a bit more work. And to make the regex more reliable the innter text match pattern `(.*?)` could be written as `([^<>]*)` for example.

Comment: this works great and even captures the h3/h4/h5 cases too ^_^ Swapping strtr($title, " .", "--") for sanitize_title($title) works very well under wordpress

Comment: Because `list` is a language construct you may omit the `$_unused` variable altogether: `list(, $h2, $title) = $match;`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `php` function to adding id to all `h2` tags automatically.

```
function h2slug($text) {
    preg_match_all("|<h2(.*)>(.*)</[^>]+>|U", $text, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($out as $header) {
        $slug = slug($header[2]);
        $header[1] = preg_replace('/(?<!\S\W\w\s)(\s?)id(\s?)="(\w*\W*)"/', '' , $header[1]);
        $text = str_replace($header[0], '<h2 id="'. $slug .'"'. $header[1] .'>'. $header[2] .'</h2>', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Using:

```
<?php echo h2slug('<h2>Lesson 1 bannanas.</h2>'); ?>
```

Export:

```
<h2 id="lesson-1-bannanas">Lesson 1 bannanas.</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way (that actually is quite simple, although it resorts to dom manipulation) is using jQuery to add a id, thats equal to the content of the h2

Comment: Well, it'd also need to replace whitespace with valid css id characters.

Comment: That I can do easily, but Im not sure if that would work linking people in, since the browser would look for the ID and not find it then JQuery would fire on document ready and add the ID and we'd be left with the html wanted, but not the browser scrolled to the correct part of the page ( also falls apart with javascript turned off )

Answer (score -2):

You could use str_replace to replace the opening h2 tag with one containing your ID

```
$tag = '<h2>My content</h2>';
$tag = str_replace('<h2>', '<h2 id = "an id">', $tag);
echo $tag;
```

Comment: I wanted something that'd automate it, whereas this requires the heading titles contents be prior knowledge