# Find H2 tag in a string and give it a ID

Tags: php, string, wordpress

Searching stackoverflow i've found a answer for my need, but I can't figure out how to use it exactly if someone could give me a hint It would be appreciated !

Here's my need, I'm using wordpress and I would to put automatic ID to <...> tags so I found "mario" who answer this:

> If you have a coherent input like
> that, then you can use regular
> expressions. In this case it's both
> very acceptable and simple:
>
> ```
> $html = preg_replace_callback("#<(h[1-6])>(.*?)</\\1>#", "retitle", $html);
>
> function retitle($match) {
>     list($_unused, $h2, $title) = $match;
>
>     $id = strtolower(strtr($title, " .", "--"));
>
>     return "<$h2 id='$id'>$title</$h2>"; }
> ```
>
> The id conversion needs a bit more work. And to make the regex more reliable the innter text match pattern `(.*?)` could be written as `([^<>]*)` for example.
>
> [H2 tag auto ID in php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987312/h2-tag-auto-id-in-php-string)

So i've tryed to apply this to my script, but that doesn't work well at all, here is my code

```
<?php 
        $html = get_the_content();
        $html = preg_replace_callback("#<(h[1-6])>(.*?)</\\1>#", "retitle", $html);
        
        function retitle($match) {
            list($_unused, $h2, $title) = $match;
            $id = strtolower(strtr($title, " .", "--"));
            return "<$h2 id='$id'>$title</$h2>";
        }
    
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); //Vérifie que le contenu existe 
                echo $html;
            endwhile; 
        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: The regex can easily fail for a variety of reasons. If for example the tags already contain a `<h2 class=xyz>` they will be overlooked. If your titles contained newlines, then you'd just had to add a `#s` regex flag.

Comment: After more verification the problem is from wordpress get_the_content() function ! That dosn't return nothing ! but if i'm getting the content with the_content(); everything's work... I gonna update this post if there probleme with the retitle function, but the problem is more from wordpress I think. Thank you for your quick answer BoltClock

Comment: Mario are you the one who answer on the other post ? If yes, could you tell me if i'm using it fine (outside the get_the_content error) and if there's a way to see if there's already a id on the h2 tag ?

Comment: @JonathanLaf: The usage seems ok, but I cannot comment on the WP function get_content_*. The regex will skip any `<h2>` that already has attributes, including existing `id=` attributes. If you wanted to filter on a specific criteria there, then phpQuery/QueryPath would be easier.

Comment: @mario Thank you ! I'll never eard about phpQuery but a quick search proof me that i'd love to work with this ! i'm currently using jQuery and really appreciate it ! Thank you !

Comment: Please consider posting future WordPress questions on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex to solve that problem.  Using domdocument:

```
if (empty($content)) return '';
$dom = new DomDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true)
$html = '<html>
           <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
           </head>
           <body>'.$content.'</body>
         </html>';
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$hTAGs = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);
foreach ($hTAGs as $hTAG) {
    if (!$hTAG->hasAttribute('id')) {
        $title = $hTAG->nodeValue;
        $id = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $title);
        $id = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]/', '', $id);
        $hTAG->setAttribute('id', $id);
    }
}
$content = '';
$children = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $content .= $dom->saveXml($child);
}
return $content;
```

Comment: Care to explain the silent `-1`?  What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: You've made a typo: `$id = iconv('URF-8'…` <– that should be `UTF-8`.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have iframe :(. The code will stop to save the node at the first one.

Comment: I change to $dom->saveHTML($child) (PHP 5.3.6) but after I have encoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever use RegEx for HTML, ok? Just accept this. Or read the numerous posts on here why not.

DOMDocument is ugly and evil. Use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) instead, it's much simpler:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = str_get_html('<h2>hello</h2><h3>world</h3><h2 id='123'>how r ya</h2>');

$h2s = $html->find("h2");

foreach($h2s as $h2)
{
    if(!$h2->hasAttribute("id")) $h2->id = "title";
}

echo $html->save();
```

Comment: DomDocument is an [implmentation of the DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR).  It's not by any means evil.  Now, if you like `Simple_Html_Dom`'s interface better, that's your perogative.  But I find it kind of odd that you say DomDocument is evil.  Look at SHD's source code some time...

Comment: I agree DomDocument is evil or at least not fun. Is better in php 5.3.6 because you can finaly use saveHTML with an node argument. But still they are not easy way to output the result as a string. I try using DomDocument for hours and switch to simple_html_dom and solve the problem in 2min.